# Changing multiple cells depending on another cell in their row

Tags: excel

I have an Excel sheet with two columns.  The first column holds names.  I also have a list of names as text file, now added as second sheet.

For each row, I want to set the second cell to a fixed value if the value of the first cell is present in the list.  Other rows should remain unchanged.

I was told to consider `VLOOKUP` but could not make up a formula.

I'm using Excel for Microsoft 365

first sheet: [image]
column `M` is the one to be changed

second sheet: [image]

The expected output would simple have entries in column `M` to be `IN` instead of `OUT`.

Comment: IF the list is in a txt file, I'm afraid you'll need VBA for this. IF the list is also in the same workbook, probably you can use COUNTIF with wildcards. Anyways, a data example of your input and expected output would be helpful

Comment: I created a new sheet and imported the list of names into a column. That sheet now has one column where each row/cell is one name. So, the first sheet has the rows I want to change, the second sheet holds the list.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, in what format would you expect a data example?

Comment: If all is in the same Excel file, I think some screenshoots or copy/paste data of **both** worksheets should be enough in this case. Also, the expected output (a manual example)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `COUNTIF`:

```
=IF(COUNTIF(List!A:A,A1),"IN","OUT")
```

[image]

Comment: With two additional steps, this answer is the solution: (1) lock the column "A" in  "A1" by writing "$A1" instead. (2) Copy the formula to all cells in column M by writing it into the cell of the first row (i.e., write `=IF(COUNTIF(Q:Q;$A1),"IN","OUT")` into cell M1), select the entire column M, and select Home > Fill > Down.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with MATCH if the Second Sheet is in the same workbook.  If it is in a separate workbook, it will still work, but only of the other workbook is open.

```
=IF( ISNUMBER( MATCH( A2,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$7, 0 ) ), "IN", "OUT" )
```

[image]

Alternatively, if you don't want to do VBA, you can pull the text file into a table in your workbook that is hidden into the data model and then reference it, but that is a long trip and can only be done on an installation that supports Power Query.

Comment: You beat me with 10 seconds :-)

Comment: @Dominique - LOL- sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Formula would be somethin like

```
=VLOOKUP(K3,Table1,2)
```

Where `Table1` is your look up,   `K3` is the value to look up (index) and `2`  is the second column you want to return

[[image: Screen shot of forumal in Action1]

Comment: But isn't the `lookup_value` of `VLOOKUP` a constant? I guess, in my use case, it should be any name of the list on the second sheet.