# IfError with else, does this function exist in Excel?

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, error-checking

While trying to help the author of [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70770749/changing-multiple-cells-depending-on-another-cell-in-their-row), I bumped (again) into the situation that I would like the following Excel function:

```
=IFERROR(value, value_if_error, value_if_no_error)
```

In other words, I'm looking for an `IFERROR()` function with an else-clause.
The issue is: it can in theory be done as follows:

```
=IF(IFERROR(function(),error_value),value_if_error,value_if_no_error)
```

But what if `error_value` is a possible outcome of `function()`? That would make it impossible to use `IFERROR()`: e.g. `function()` returns a string, which can be anything, also an empty string, but it might also generate an error.

**Edit: some clarification**

Let me give an example:

```
=IFERROR(B3, "weird")
```

In "B3", there is a function, which returns a string, but even in case the value of this string is "weird", this is ok. How can I distinguish the erroneous case and the case where "weird" is a normal correct result?

As an image says more than a thousand words:

[image]

Comment: How is `value_if_no_error` different from `value`?

Comment: iferror() returns the value, or if that is an error then it returns the value_if_error. There are only two possibilities here.

Comment: But you could wrap iferror() with an if() and set other conditions.

Comment: Do you mean `IF(ISERROR(`?

Comment: @P.b: You're right, I didn't know this function existed. Please add it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: there is also iserr() which excludes #NA

Comment: I find scrolling through the function list very helpful, buit I still have the function reference boof from Excel V4 that lists most of them... Was a good read at the time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Next to `IFERROR()`, there also is the `ISERROR()` function, which can be used as an input for an `IF()`-clause:

`=IF(ISERROR(value),value_if_error,value_if_no_error)`